# Capturing text with a bookmarklet in IOS7

Tags: iphone, safari, ipod-touch, bookmarks, javascript

Is it possible to capture text from Safari using a bookmarklet on an iPod Touch/iPhone when running iOS7?

In iOS6 I could select text, and then open a bookmarklet (like [this one for example](https://bitbucket.org/mgaudet/dayonebookmarklet/src/1062388c8320f72ca099f4e684a9d9822d7e905c/dayone.html?at=master)) which grabbed the text using `window.getSelection()`.

However, it seems in iOS7, any action to invoke a bookmarklet deselects the text. Am I just missing something, or is this broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK it's no longer possible.

Tried looking at the contents of `window.getSelection()` by remote debugging my iPhone through Safari. Text is indeed deselected. But even visually, I'm able to see that text is deselected when you tap a link or open the bookmarks menu.

In regards to describing this as *"broken"*, I suppose it's a matter of how you look at it. It could be argued that deselecting is the *correct* behavior and therefore I doubt it's something that'll get "fixed".

Comment: I thought so. Perhaps later in the month when I have a little more time I'll file a radar... not today alas.

Comment: Nice work both of you - it's a pretty ugly regression so if someone files a radar, pls post it here and I'll gladly dupe it.

Comment: @bmike Submitted as radar 15656765 -- https://gist.github.com/mgaudet/7947377

Comment: @MatthewG. Perfect. Dupe is at http://www.openradar.me/15656950 and also check out http://www.quickradar.com if you're so inclined.

Comment: @bmike looks cool: Bookmarked. If I ever get off my butt and start doing development on apple platforms, it'll come in handy.

Comment: @bmike Yeah, nifty utility!